# API for continuously redrawing polygons while panning?

Tags: leaflet

Is there a way method in the API to force the SVG polygons to re-render while I drag? As opposed to rendering a clipped version that re-renders when I finish dragging?

I tried to run `.redraw()` in the `onMove` callback, but that didn't solve it for me- so I assume `redraw` doesn't actually rerender?

Comment: Explicitly create a `L.Renderer` (either a `L.Canvas` or a `L.SVG`) with a value of `1`  for its `padding` option. That'll still redraw everything on drag end, but the drawn area will be thrice the map's width and height, preventing the user from seeing any clipped geometries.

Comment: I had thought about this, but the problem is that it wouldn't work with programmatic panning